# How to customize Service credentials in Message Hub

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

When we create a message hub instance in bluemix, we can see a service credentials tab on the screen. The data is in json format and not editable:

"user": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Is there any method to customize or edit the username and password?

Answer (score 2):

no, there is no way for you to customise or edit the username and password.

You can delete the credentials you have, and use the "new credential" button to generate a new username and password, but these will also be randomly generated for you. (I would recommend you do delete the credentials you have shared here...)